# Is it possible to use the Twitter Search API to figure out if search keyword is a person/name (popular)?

Tags: json, api, twitter

I would like to change a few options on my search API in case the keyword searched is a popular person or even place. Is there a way to determine this using the JSON GET API response. I looked at options like result_type, but it does not seem like there is anything obvious.

I can afford to do multiple calls to improve the relevance of my results. Would this open up some possibilities?

Comment: please try and make your question clearer, perhaps give an example of the result you are looking for.

Comment: Yep after having looked at the answer I do realize I had not conveyed my question correctly. Also I think instead of trying to infer more about the search keyword by making different call, it would be better to look at the result which also carries meta data about the results.

But thanks for suggestions in the answers. There some other ideas I got out of the links you have sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start by rephrasing your question:  you want to determine if a keyword is a person.  And further, if that person is popular, ie, has a lot of followers?  Or do you mean, the keyword is a person, and that person's real name (not screen_name) is mentioned often?

Unless the keyword is the twitter screen_name, I don't think you'll have much luck determining the number of followers.  You'd need to infer the name -> twitter screen_name.

If you want to determine how popular a keyword is, then sure, you can use the https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/filter call to get the frequency over time of a particular word.  Then get a baseline on some other keywords to figure out if this frequency was higher/lower than your baseline.

Or you could just use infochimps API: http://www.infochimps.com/datasets/twitter-word-usage

Answer (score 1):

Twitter search api provides ways for developers to search through tweets and users.

If you want to see relevant users according to the given keyword, you can use user/search api and see whether the keyword returns any relevant user or not.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search

Since you are ok with having multiple calls you can have an advanced search using twitter search api. You can first check whether there is any twitter user by searching through "from" operator, and if you retrieve any tweet, you would know that the searched keyword is a username of a twitter user. Unfortunately you can only do such a search using username, so you will need the exact user names of twitter accounts.

> from:twitterapi   sent from the user @twitterapi

And you can have a similar scenario for the places by following the instructions on the following page: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/finding-tweets-about-places